# Multi files to addon

Tags: add-on

I've spend a lot of time testing several functionalities in Blender and it works great. Each functionality has some operators, methods, custom variables and one panel contained in a separate script. So I need to load each script each time I start Blender or make changes in the code.

This is ok, for testing and POC, but I would like to make it a single addon. I have searched all over the place and it seems that Blender/python is not really too glad of multiple files. I have tried the Blender Development (by Jacque Lucke) extension for VS Code, which has an auto load_and_registre function. But It gets bugged down in some path_scanning_and_modifying-rabbit hole and crashes.

Do any of you have some nice toturial or documentation? Preferably starting at the very start and going all the way to a working addon (with many files)

Comment: Probably this is also helpful: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/creating-multifile-add-on-for-blender/

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Every blender addon is simply a python package with some small differences. if you use multiple files in your addon (package) you should have an `__init__.py` file in the main folder (*and also in every folder in your directory so you can import them  as your local packages*). blender recognizes your package as an addon, if you have `bl_info` (*dictionary*) and `register` and `unregister` functions in your `__init__.py` file. as described in the [*manual*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html) the simplest example of addons is:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Test Add-on",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "Object",
}
def register():
    print("Hello World")
def unregister():
    print("Goodbye World")
```

relative importing also works because its python but importing is also a little bit different in addons. you should check if bpy module is added before. for example if you have `utils` and `draw` package(folders including `__init__.py` files) or modules(`*.py` files) you should import them like this:

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    importlib.reload(utils)
    importlib.reload(draw)
else:
    from . import utils
    from . import draw
```

the rest is as same as every python package and depends on you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of the referenced text files associated with the project with `bpy.data.texts`. Access your scripts like this: `bpy.data.texts['myScript.py']`. You can then extract its content as a string and execute it:

```
exec(bpy.data.texts['myScript.py'].as_string())
```

Create a main script and execute all your scripts from this one. For example:

main.py

```
exec(bpy.data.texts['myScript1.py'].as_string())
exec(bpy.data.texts['myScript2.py'].as_string())
```

myScript1.py

```
print("1")
```

myScript2.py

```
print("1")
```

Output:

```
1
2
```